How does the setting SharePoint 'Allow items from this site to be downloaded to offline clients' affect the OneDrive 'Files on Demand' feature?
I'm considering to limiting the use of offline data on my endpoints however the exact effects are unclear to me.
When setting the option 'Allow items from this site to be downloaded to offline clients?' to 'No' under a SharePoint Site Settings > Search and Offline Availability as (the GUI option) also described in this article.

I wonder what will happen to the OneDrive Desktop clients that already synced the full site locally. Will local OneDrive in Windows Explorer simply switch the 'Files on Demand' from "Always" or "Locally available" to "Online-only"? Also, will already synced data be removed locally? Meaning, clients can still access all data from Explorer as before but only when they are online? What other effects will this have?

